# How do I choose a suitable MOSFET driver?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, mosfet-driver, sic

Can I drive [C3M0045065K](https://assets.wolfspeed.com/uploads/2024/01/Wolfspeed_C3M0045065K_data_sheet.pdf) SiC MOSFET if I use Infineon-[1EDI20N12AF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-1EDI60N12AF-DataSheet-v01_10-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a3043427ac3e201428e5da08f372a)?

I read in the specifications that the MOSFET turn-off voltage needs to be -4 V, but I only have a square wave signal of plus or minus 5V for driver input signal.

If I want to drive this transistor correctly，is there a more suitable driver?

Can we pursue faster frequencies if I use GaN MOSFETs?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the 1EDIxx driver and you need to adjust the supply voltage to -4 V as per the device data sheet. The driver is good to handle -4 V as well.
Please check the below link of data sheet on page number 11 table 3, which clearly shows that the operating VCC2 to Gnd2 voltage can go up to 35 V. So, as per the MOSFET data sheet, the operating voltage is 15-(-4)= 19 V which is well under limit of 35 V.
[image: Power supply range on output side]
[1EDIxx data sheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-1EDI60N12AF-DataSheet-v01_10-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a3043427ac3e201428e5da08f372a&?utm_source=electronicstackexchange&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=external_community_engagement)

Disclosure: I work as a support engineer with Infineon at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot. By the way, I saw that the maximum switching speed is 1M. Can it be faster? For example, 10MHz. Or there are other components?

Comment: The OP has a ±5V source only, as indicated in the question body *"but I only have a square wave signal of plus or minus 5V"*. With +5V drive signal the MOSFET can't be driven properly to switch tens of amps.  Since the OP has no external voltage sources higher than 5V the IC doesn't seem to be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I only have a square wave signal of plus or minus 5V for driver input signal.

> If I want to drive this transistor correctly，is there a more suitable driver?

The MOSFET's manufacturer recommends 15V for turn-on signal, although the threshold is around 3V *(for a few milliamps of drain current, of course)*. The Note (1) under the KEY PARAMETERS table, and the app note it refers to, clearly indicate that. So if you don't have the required supply voltages then you can't simply drive the MOSFET "properly".

The driver IC has nothing to do for this purpose.

You can, however, use a gate drive transformer to boost the drive voltage, as an alternative solution. Make sure your ±5V power supplies are able to source the peak currents that the MOSFET requires.

PS: Asking for product recommendation is off-topic but still the question has a technical side relates to electrical design. Hence my answer.

Comment: Now that I know that gate drive transformer exists, I will look for information about it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  All you really need is some peak-to-peak voltage swing.

Realize that the gate draws very little DC current, therefore it can be capacitor-coupled at little expense to your circuit (in terms of bias current or complexity).

From the 1EDI20N12AF datasheet:

[image]

Notice the emitter is capacitor-coupled between supplies.  *You still need to ensure this voltage is maintained*, but this can be done with for example a resistor divider, or zener diode and pull-up resistor, or bipolar (asymmetrical) supply, etc.

Whether this renders the input non-common-ground for other purposes, I don't know, but for transistors this fast, it's probably not a great idea to have too much connection in common between controller/driver and power stage.  That is: isolated gate drive is not a bad idea.  Digital isolators readily furnish the gate signal, and a DC-DC converter provides power.

I wouldn't expect a bootstrap gate driver to be of much help, for example, because the transient voltage overshoot (due to load current, switching speed and source lead inductance) can easily be 10s of volts, exceeding the rating of the driver.  (That said, I have seen drivers with a transient rating of -30, even -100V I think, for very short periods.  It's still not a great look; realize such drivers are inactive during the transient -- they can only communicate state changes from input to output while operating voltages are normal.  Most of the time, you'll have enough dead time that this isn't a concern, so it can work just fine, but still, it's more things to account for.)

Note that either terminal (gate or source/emitter) can be cap-coupled.  On the gate side, a negative bias resistor plus "DC restore" circuit might be used.  Then the driver can be common-ground (but again, with the above concerns, that might not mean much).

GaN transistors are even faster, and unlikely to be helpful to a beginner.  Even plain Si is fast enough, newbies encounter problems with it: the understanding of loop inductance, proper layout, and switching speed.  SiC and GaN only compound these issues.

Comment: thanks! The digital isolators can it be used for fast high frequency switching?

Comment: Digital isolators are available over 100Mbps, far more than is needed here; suffice it to say they can do high speed / low propagation delay.